# T-algebra and a matrix paradigm over the algebra

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-analysis, python, artificial-intelligence

We established a novel semisimple commutative algebra called t-algebra, which is backward-compatible to the field of complex numbers. Many notions of complex numbers and matrices are generalized. The notion of metric space is generalized. We even believe we can generalize the notion of manifolds in a straightforward backward-compatible manner.

We contend that the magnificent edifices of data analytics, machine intelligence, and beyond should have been built over the t-algebra rather than the classical simple algebra (i.e., the field of complex numbers).
We have open-sourced our MATLAB functions at the following URL.
https://github.com/liaoliang2020/talgebra

A detailed document for the code repository is now in preparation. Is there someone interested in rewriting those functions to a Python version?

As far as I know, Hamilton’s quaternions and other hypercomplex numbers in Clifford algebra are efforts to generalize complex numbers. However, they are either non-commutative or non-Euclid-like. I think commutativity and Euclid-likeness are probably critical in generalized data analytics.
Whether there are some existing commutative algebras of generalized scalars and generalized matrix paradigms over them?  If any, I would like to know more of them.

Big thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid the main sense of this post is not really a question - even the sentence with a question mark is more of a request than a question. The [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help?mnu=1) has details about what sorts of questions are appropriate for this site - perhaps you will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this site. If this post is not appropriate, I can delete it if it is against the rule or modify it to comply with the rule.  --- Whether there are some existed commutative algebras of generalized scalars and generalized matrix paradigms over them? To know or not to know, that's a question now :)